How do I extend an existing Grafana Plugin? (the node graph plugin)
I want to extend the functionality of the Node Graph plugin in Grafana. Using the default plugin as a base to start from.
My current approach is to download the folder of the Node Graph plugin and start from there, but it is leading to resolving a string of dependencies.
Is there a simpler way of doing it?
I have tried downloading the Node Graph folder from https://github.com/grafana/grafana/tree/main/public/app/plugins/panel/nodeGraph and replacing it for the src folder in the new base plugin from npx create-grafan-plugin.
But the web of dependencies is very hard to resolve here.
